# Get type namespace with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

How I can get namespace of IdentifierName type in MethodBody?

```
private void GetType(MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
{
    var nodes = method.Body.ChildNodes().ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i <nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        var desNodes = nodes[i].DescendantNodes().ToList();
        for (int k = 0; k < desNodes.Count; k++)
        {
            if(desNodes[k].GetType() == typeof(IdentifierNameSyntax))
                //what's next?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more description for your problem

Comment: For example: if the method has Console.ReadLine then GetType should return System.Console

Comment: I just want to get all unnecessary usings in file.